# What is the better condition to check for convergence of a complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If you have a series $$a_0, a_1, a_2, ... $$ and all of them are complex. Now if I am to find whether this series converges or not..

Should I have be to be checking $|a_n -a_{n-1}| < \epsilon$ or $|a_n| - |a_{n-1}| < \epsilon $ for some arbitrary chosen epsilon.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a series; it's a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=\sqrt{n}$ satisfies both inequalities, but doesn't converge.

You should be checking that $|a_n -a_m| < \epsilon$ for all $m,n\geq N$ (not just $m=n+1$) for some $N>0$ (definition of Cauchy-sequence), because $\mathbb{C}$ is a Banach space, and hence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ will converge.

Comment: Cauchy sequences rely on completeness of the space to be guaranteed to converge. There is a more general definition of convergence (not far from this one) that is independent of the completeness of the space.

Comment: Maybe its just me , but why is it $|a_n - a_m|$ and not $|a_n| - |a_m|$ ? And would you say that the above is a sufficient condition for convergence ?

Comment: @153armstrong By the reverse triangle inequality $||a_n| - |a_m||\leq |a_n - a_m|$. Convergence implies $|a_n| - |a_m|<\varepsilon$ but not the other way around, so no.

Answer (score 0):

$\log(n) $ stands as counter example to both.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the definition of convergence. (It is necessary, but not sufficient.)

A sequence in a metric space $i \mapsto a_i$ converges to a value $L$ if:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0$ s.t. $n>N \implies \mid a_n - L \mid < \epsilon$

That is, we can make terms in a series after a specific point grow *arbitrarily close* to a unique limit L.

Since the complex numbers are a complete metric space, this L will exist if and only if the sequence is convergent.

---

A definition somewhat like the one you proposed is similar to the notion of convergence: A sequence in a metric space is Cauchy if

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0$ s.t. $m, n>N \implies \mid a_m - a_n \mid < \epsilon$

That is, all terms after a point get arbitrarily close to *each other*, not just the preceding point.

In what is called a *complete metric space*, all Cauchy sequences are convergent (i.e. they have a limit L in the space) and all convergent sequences are Cauchy. The real numbers and the complex numbers form a complete metric space. The rational numbers do not. I leave it as an exercise to you to give me a Cauchy sequence in the rationals that has no rational limit.